# Will overridden background-images styles for retina devices download both images?

Tags: css, mobile

With the following I want to use larger background images for double density displays. However will devices that support the media query only download the larger image or will they download both?

```
.logo {
    background: url('logo.jpg');
}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

     .logo {
         background: url('logo-double-density.jpg');
         background-size: 40px 40px; //size is half of the actual image 
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will only download the large image, as the previous background property has been overwritten.

You can test this easily with your browser (I use Chrome, but I'm sure others will do the same thing).

Make some CSS like

```
body {
    background-image: url(somethingThatDoesNotExist.jpg);
}

body {
    background-image: url(somethingElseThatDoesNotExist.jpg);
}
```

And look in your console to see the 404 errors - you'll only get one: http://jsfiddle.net/RYPu9/

Answer (score 0):

Do you use ***Modernizr***? If so, that will make life easier because all you do in the css is:

```
.logo {background: url("../logo.svg") no-repeat;}
.no-svg .logo {background: url("../logo.png") no-repeat;}
```